# How to migrate ec2 and rds from region to another?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

In the start when I was new to aws I was not knowing that how much the selection of regions impact the performance of the system. At that time I created my  ec2 and rds instances in sydney but the system will be used in Mexico which is 14000+ km away from Sydney.

Now a lot of configurations are done on those instances. Is there any way I can move these instances to another region?
similarly how i can move other configuration like route 53 and elastic ips as well?

Comment: Elastic IP addresses cannot be moved between regions. However, you should avoid hard-coding IP addresses where possible, and instead use domain names to point to IP addresses. You should just be able to edit the A-Record to point to a different IP address.

Comment: yes i did that thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not possible to move an existing instance to another subnet, Availability Zone, or VPC. Instead, you can manually migrate the instance by creating a new Amazon Machine Image (AMI) from the source instance. Then, launch a new instance using the new AMI in the desired subnet, Availability Zone, or VPC. Finally, you can reassign any Elastic IP addresses from the source instance to the new instance.

More details in: [Move an Amazon EC2 instance to another subnet, Availability Zone, or VPC](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/move-ec2-instance/)

Comment: To copy the AMI to another Region, find the AMI in the management console and select **Copy AMI**. The copied AMI can then be used to launch a new Amazon EC2 instance in the other region. It will contain a complete copy of the disks from the original instance.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thanks Yes that will be better approach to spin up new EC2 instance with the existing AMI

Comment: and what about route 53 and other configurations?

Comment: @SwiftSolutions You made no mention of Route 53 or other configurations in your question.

Comment: @SwiftSolutions to move configuration of services between regions, the best known way to me is to build those services as cloud formation templates to begin with. Then you can add just a parameter of "Region" and change it's value to re-create same services in new region. Yet to move all config, i wonder if that's possible. You just need to re-create. Things like Ec2 or database can restore from snapshots, yet route53 config does not have anything like that.

Comment: Second half of the answer is copied from https://medium.com/@webcore1/solved-how-to-copy-move-aws-rds-to-another-region-72bb0f8ea690 . Don't be so shameless and plagiarise other's answers at least give some credit. smh